# How to place the form on the screen the mouse is currently on?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, coordinates, window-position

Have searched the web a while but didn't find what I was looking for.
Maybe someone can help me. Here's the core code: http://pastebin.com/qWEFrAuC

Comment: I believe I understand your question, but what I would like to know is wether you want to place the form on the same screen as the cursor _when the form is shown_ or if you want to do it _whenever you move the cursor there_.

Comment: That's actually how the OS decides where to put your first window.  Sounds like you want to create *another* window when you already have one.   Not that great an idea, how does the user tell you to create it?

Comment: I want the form to ALWAYS be on the screen that the cursor is on.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do, you're creating this as a "custom cursor", right? You should not move the `PictureBox` but the entire form instead. Also, do you want one form that follows the mouse, or one form on every screen?

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the screens to look for the mouse position into their bounds.

This example will center a Form into the screen on which the mouse is currently on, if you want to preserve the position during the window moving, a little bit of effort from your side is required.

To determine the screen:

```
Dim scr As Screen =
    Screen.AllScreens.Where(Function(x) x.Bounds.Contains(Control.MousePosition)).Single
```

To center the form on the screen:

```
CenterToScreen(Me, scr)

Public Shared Function CenterToScreen(ByVal f As Form, ByVal display As Screen) As Point

    If (display Is Nothing) Then
        display = Screen.PrimaryScreen
    End If

    Dim location As New Point With
        {
            .X = ((display.Bounds.Width - f.Bounds.Size.Width) \ 2),
            .Y = ((display.Bounds.Height - f.Bounds.Size.Height) \ 2)
        }

    f.Location = location

    Return location ' Return the new coordinates of the source Form.

End Function
```

Note: The function is part of **[my free API: ElektroKit](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.Application.UI/Tools/Gui/GuiUtil.vb)**, where you could get more useful snippets like that one related to the window positioning on Class:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but out of curiosity I'd like to know why you loop through the screens instead of just calling `Screen.FromPoint()`?

Comment: @Visual Vincent Only to show another different solution than the published one, If I do that, my answer could be considered "a copy".

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE! x2 - picturebox should move with window form.

From what I can know understand, if the mouse leave the form, it will change to the opposite screen monitor (it does for me, though i only have 2 monitors)the amount of monitors you have could be more than 2 but so let me know how you go.

```
    Private Sub Form1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
    If Me.DesktopLocation = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Location Then
        Me.DesktopLocation = Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100))
    Else
        Me.DesktopLocation = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Location
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe he wants to place the form at the same screen where the mouse pointer is. Like if the mouse is at screen no. 3, then place the form at screen no. 3.

Comment: possibly, he/she didn't mention anything about multiple screens, i guess we will have to wait and see what they say.

Comment: Why would he even say _"on **the** screen"_ if he didn't have several? :)

Comment: yeah that's true, Touche!

Comment: Well. None of these seemed to have worked for me. I want a picture to be displayed next to the cursor of the user on all screens, but it only works on the primary screen. Maybe someone has another idea?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the numbers around with the code that i posed,

Comment: also as for the picture, do you have any code we can look at please/

Comment: could you edit your question with the code? and also have "UPDATE" above it so other people dont have to read through our comments.

Answer (score 0):

This will put your form in the center of the screen where the mouse pointer is located.

```
Private Sub CenterToCurrentScreen()
    Dim CurrentScreen As Screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position)
    Me.Location = New Point( _
                           (CurrentScreen.Bounds.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2), _
                           (CurrentScreen.Bounds.Height / 2) - (Me.Height / 2))
End Sub
```

For example: calling `CenterToCurrentScreen()` when the mouse pointer is on *Screen 3* will put your form in the center of *Screen 3*.

`Screen.FromPoint()` will give you the screen at the specified coordinates and `Cursor.Position` will give you the coordinates of the mouse pointer.